# Delete Folders, Subfolders and All Files from a S3 bucket older than X days

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a S3 bucket with the below architecture -

```
Bucket
|__2019-08-23/
|   |__SubFolder1
|      |__Files
|
|__2019-08-22/
   |__SubFolder2
```

I want to delete all folders, subfolders and files within which are older than X days.

How can that be done? I am not sure if S3 LifeCycle can be used for this ?

Also when I do -

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucket/
```

I get this -

```
PRE 2019-08-23/
PRE 2019-08-22/
```

Why do I see PRE in front of the folder name?

As per the valuable comments I tried this -

```
$ Number=1;current_date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d);
past_date=$(date -d "$current_date - $Number days" +%Y-%m-%d);
aws s3api list-objects --bucket bucketname --query 'Contents[?LastModified<=$past_date ].{Key:Key,LastModified: LastModified}' --output text |  xargs -I {} aws  s3 rm bucketname/{}
```

I am trying to remove all files which are 1 day old. But I get this error -

```
Bad jmespath expression: Unknown token $:
Contents[?LastModified<=$past_date ].{Key:Key,LastModified: LastModified}
```

How can I pass a variable in lastmodified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use lifecycle, a lambda function if you have more complex logic or command line.

here is an example using command line:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket your-bucket --query 'Contents[?LastModified>=`2019-01-01` ].{Key:Key,LastModified: LastModified}' --prefix "2019-01-01" --output text |  xargs -I {} aws  s3 rm s3://your-bucket/{}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Elzo's answer already covers the life cycle policy and how to delete the objects, therefore here I have an answer for the second part of your question:

*PRE* stands for *PREFIX* as stated in the aws s3 cli's manual.

If you run `aws s3 ls help` you will come across the following section:

> The  following  ls  command  lists  objects and common prefixes under
>   a
>          specified bucket and prefix.  In this example, the user owns the bucket
>          mybucket  with the objects test.txt and somePrefix/test.txt.  The Last-
>          WriteTime and Length are arbitrary. Note that since the ls command  has
>          no  interaction  with the local filesystem, the s3:// URI scheme is not
>          required to resolve ambiguity and may be omitted:
>
> ```
>       aws s3 ls s3://mybucket
>
>    Output:
>
>                                  PRE somePrefix/
>       2013-07-25 17:06:27         88 test.txt
> ```

This is just to differentiate keys that have a prefix (split by forward slashes) from keys that don't.

Therefore, if your key is `prefix/key01` you will always see a `PRE` in front of it. However, if your key is `key01`, then `PRE` is not shown.

Keep in mind that S3 does not work with *directories* even though you can tell otherwise when looking from the UI. S3's file structure is just one flat single-level container of files.

From the docs:

> In Amazon S3, buckets and objects are the primary resources, where
>   objects are stored in buckets. Amazon S3 has a flat structure with no
>   hierarchy like you would see in a file system. However, for the sake
>   of organizational simplicity, the Amazon S3 console supports the
>   folder concept as a means of grouping objects. Amazon S3 does this by
>   using a shared name prefix for objects (that is, objects that have
>   names that begin with a common string). Object names are also referred
>   to as key names.
>
> For example, you can create a folder in the console called photos, and
>   store an object named myphoto.jpg in it. The object is then stored
>   with the key name photos/myphoto.jpg, where photos/ is the prefix.

Answer (score -1):

S3 Lifecycle can be used for buckets. For folders and subfolder management, you can write a simple AWS lambda to delete the folders and sub folders which are xx days old. Leverage S3 AWS SDK for JavaScript or Java or Python, etc. to develop the Lambda.

Comment: One of the OP's question is: Why do I see PRE in front of the folder name. Your answer does not give an answer to it at all. Also, there are no folders/subfolders in a S3 object. Everything in S3 is a key, which may or may not contain slashes (which ends up creating a false impression of directories). Furthermore, you provide a very general overview of what should be done. @Elzo's answer is what you should be aiming for.